# How to get the Text property of each form

Tags: c#, winforms, text, types, getproperty

I have been searching for almost a week now, but I can't seem to solve my simple problem. I want to get all the name and text properties of all the forms in my project.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Reflection;

Type Myforms = typeof(Form);
foreach (Type formtype in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (Myforms.IsAssignableFrom(formtype))
    {
      MessageBox.Show(formtype.Name.ToString()); // shows all name of form
      MessageBox.Show(formtype.GetProperty("Text").GetValue(type,null).ToString()); // it shows null exception
    }
}
```

I need the name and the `.Text` of the form to store it in the database to control user privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show(formtype.GetProperty("Text").GetValue(type,null).ToString());` shows exception because you need an instance of `Form` to get its `Text` property as Form does not static Text property.

To get the default Text property create a instance

```
var frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formtype);
MessageBox.Show(formtype.GetProperty("Text").GetValue(frm, null).ToString());
```

Comment: hi itried that code and it shown me an error An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.. how can i solve this

Comment: @Mandz fixed, try it again m8 !

Comment: AppDeveloper i have found the problem. i deleted public MaintainFormFrm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Answer (score 1):

To read properties, you need to make **new instance of the form**. Above you're browsing all the types that are inheriting from the `Form`-class. You can read the different Form-class names, but that's it.

To read the `Text`-property, you need to browse instances of your `Forms`. You can use `Application.OpenForms` to read the `Text` and `Name` properties of your open forms.

You can try this to read the properties:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> formDetails = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
Type formType = typeof(Form);
foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
   if (formType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
   {
      using (var frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type))
      {
         formDetails.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(frm.Name, frm.Text));
      }
   }
}
```

I fixed the code and it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

The properties `.Text` and `.Name` are not static. So, you can't get the value of that property without calling a Constructor of that form. You must create an object of that form to read the property.

```
List<String> formList = new List<String>();
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

foreach (Type t in myAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
    {
        ConstructorInfo ctor = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (ctor != null)
        {
            Form f = (Form)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });
            formList.Add("Text: " +  f.Text + ";Name: " + f.Name);
        }
    }
}
```